# Connecting a Mobile App to multiple BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, sfmc-business-unit

I am looking to understand the best practice for the scenario when a single app needs to be connected to multiple market-based BUs in order to allow each market to send push notifications to the contacts in their region. The BU structure is the following:

- **Parent BU** (Master of contact records & connected to SFDC)

  - **Market A BU** (with contact records for Market A only and journey's/automations for the market A only)
  - **Market B BU** (with contact records for Market B only and journey's/automations for the market B only)
  - ... (multiple futher market specific BUs)

The app in question is a single global app and therefore we are wanting to integrate the SDK once globally and then allow each market to manage mobilePush notifications separately.

What is the best practice in this situation? If we integrate the app with the parent BU will each market be able to push notifications to their contacts from within their market BU (within journey builder etc)?

We want to limit the ability for a market to have access to the parent BU where possible, so it is vital that they only have access to their market BU (a single MID)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a supported use-case as of 20220114.  It can be accomplished, but it should not be done.

The application can launch with the configuration of your global BU and be switched to a child BU once the user is identified, but the data in the parent BU will become stale overtime and there's no guarantee that it will continue to work without some sort of synchronization -- which is not offered out of the box.

Comment: would the recommendation here therefore be to integrate the app with the global BU only? Would you also recommend to do all segmentation at the global BU level and run all mobile push journeys within that BU?

Comment: My recommendation would be to reach out through your account representative for assistance.